# Acces to config variable when testing a package in laravel

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-testing

I'm writing a test in Laravel and I want to unittest this piece of code:

```
if (file_exists(\Config::get('maintenance.dir.api'))) {
        throw new ServiceUnavailableException('We are down for maintenance');
    }
```

I'm using **Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase** and I can't access to the config variables from the main app in the test. In my package, I don't have any config. Can I mock the config folder or something like that?

Thank you!

Comment: are you trying to get any config from `.env` file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can 'mock' config variables by simply setting them:

`config(['maintenance.dir.api' => 'mock value'])`

Comment: Make sure you don't miss out the answer acceptance! @FranRoaPrieto!

Comment: Is there any other documentation available about this way of mocking config variables?